# Resolving TRY_PARSE() overflow with datetime in SQL Server 2012. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I recently started changing queries to use `TRY_PARSE()` but I run into a problem when the resulting date is before the year 1753. For example:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('01-Jan-0001' AS datetime)
```

Results in a .NET error:

```
Msg 6521, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during statement execution: 
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: 
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan value)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime value)
   at System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.CXVariantBase.DateTimeToSSDate(DateTime dt)
```

My guess is SQL is just running a direct .NET `DateTime.TryParse()` and converting straight to `SqlDateTime` without checking and returning `NULL` in such instances (as I'd expect the behavior to be). I'd check myself but the catch 22 here is how can you check the validity of the date before parsing when you need to parse to check the validity?
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DateTime2 instead of DateTime

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('01-Jan-0001' AS datetime2)

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, '01-Jan-0001')
```

And one more thing

Use `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `TRY_PARSE`:

- [`TRY_PARSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx): Returns the result of the expression, translated to the requested data type, or null if the cast fails.
- [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx): Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, '12/31/2010') AS Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overflow you just need to change to `DATETIME2` datatype. Below is date ranges of two Date datatypes.

`DATETIME` Date range: January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

`DATETIME2` Date range: 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the culture parameter of `TRY_PARSE` you could use `TRY_CONVERT` instead.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '01-Jan-0001')
```

Comment: Isin't `1/1/1753` signifies minimum date value for the datetime type in sql server . that's y sql is throwing error with date range. Replacing it with `datetime2` type solves the problem

Comment: @praveen the question as I read it is about how you can check if a string value is a valid `datetime` value without getting the exception when the value is out of range for a `datetime`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `TRY_CONVERT()` doesn't hold up. The culture is needed in so far as the default local culture, especially when the time of day is a part of the field as well. The example I put wasn't real world. That being said, `datetime2` gets me a year and to check the year for `datetime` conversion and migrate to `datetime2` where possible. Cool

Comment: @AltonXL If you update the question with what is your "real world" problem you might get a different solution.