# SQL DateTime overflow error in inserting time values

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert a particular time into my database from a combobox. If I select one of its index then it gives a value equal to it.

I have 3 fields that I'd use in future purposes and its the following:

- time varchar(30)
- timestart datetime
- timeend datetime

But when I try to insert it into my database it gives an error that say SQL DateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM"

I had trouble in inserting the "timestart" and "timeend" values to my database.

**This is my code for inserting the values into my database.**

```
   Try
            comm.CommandText = "insert into Schedule(sched_id, timestart,timeend, room, day,session, course, section, subject, instructor,time) values (@field1,@field2,@field3,@field4,@field5,@field6,@field7,@field8,@field9,@field10,@field11)"
            comm.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            With comm
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", txtSched_ID.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", timebegin)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field3", timeend)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field4", txtRoom.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field5", cmbDay.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field6", cmbSession.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field7", txtCourse.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field8", txtSection.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field9", txtSubject.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field10", cmbInstructor.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field11", timestg)
            End With
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            comm.Dispose()
            comm.Parameters.Clear()
            MsgBox("Records Successfully Saved")
            clear()
            con.Close()
            Me.fillListViewSchedule()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

and this is my code in declaring the values of my "timestart" and "timeend"

```
      Private Sub cmbTime_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbTime.SelectedIndexChanged


    If cmbTime.Text = "7:00 AM - 10:00 AM" Then
        timestg = "7:00 AM - 10:00 AM"
        timebegin = #7:00:00 AM#
        timeend = #10:00:00 AM#
    ElseIf cmbTime.Text = "10:00 AM - 1:00 PM" Then
        timestg = "10:00 AM - 1:00 PM"
        timebegin = #10:01:00 AM#
        timeend = #1:00:00 PM#
    ElseIf cmbTime.Text = "1:00 PM - 4:00 PM" Then
        timestg = "1:00 PM - 4:00 PM"
        timebegin = #1:01:00 PM#
        timeend = #4:00:00 PM#
    ElseIf cmbTime.Text = "4:00 PM - 7:00 PM" Then
        timestg = "4:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
        timebegin = #4:01:00 PM#
        timeend = #7:00:00 PM#
    ElseIf cmbTime.Text = "7:00 PM - 10:00 PM" Then
        timestg = "7:00 PM - 10:00 PM"
        timebegin = #7:01:00 PM#
        timeend = #10:00:00 PM#
    End If
End Sub
```

and I declare this to the top of my page..

```
   Dim timebegin As DateTime
Dim timeend As DateTime
Dim timestg As String
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving TRY\_PARSE() overflow with datetime in SQL Server 2012. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255077/resolving-try-parse-overflow-with-datetime-in-sql-server-2012-must-be-between)

Comment: use datetime2: it has the same range of the .NET Datetime datatype.

Comment: 7:00 AM - 10:00 AM is not DateTime type

Comment: yeah.. it is a string.. i input "7:00 AM - 10:00PM" to string to a varchar data field type